# I want to know the meaning of the value coming from the jmeter backend listener

Tags: jmeter, influxdb-2

[Jmeter backend listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myRIA.png)

I send the result value to influxdb through this backend listener

And I can receive this value.

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/421nJ.png)

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7UvX.png)

However, I don't know what the meaning of this value is.

Can you help me? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "meanings" are listed under [Metrics Exposed](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html#metrics) JMeter user manual entry

> **15.1.1 Thread/Virtual Users metrics**
>
> Thread metrics are the following:
>
> `<rootMetricsPrefix>test.minAT`
> Min active threads
>
> `<rootMetricsPrefix>test.maxAT`
> Max active threads
>
> `<rootMetricsPrefix>test.meanAT`
> Mean active threads
>
> `<rootMetricsPrefix>test.startedT`
> Started threads
>
> `<rootMetricsPrefix>test.endedT`
> Finished threads
>
> **15.1.2 Response times metrics**
>
> Response related metrics are the following:
>
> `<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ok.count`
> Number of successful responses for sampler name
>
> `<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.h.count`
> Server hits per seconds, this metric cumulates Sample Result and Sub results (if >using Transaction Controller, "Generate parent sampler" should be unchecked)
>
> `<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ok.min`
> Min response time for successful responses of sampler name
>
> `<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ok.max`
> Max response time for successful responses of sampler name
>
> `<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ok.avg`
> Average response time for successful responses of sampler name.
>
> `<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ok.pct<percentileValue>`
> Percentile computed for successful responses of sampler name. There will be one >metric for each calculated value.
>
> `<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ko.count`
> Number of failed responses for sampler name
>
> `<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ko.min`
> Min response time for failed responses of sampler name
>
> `<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ko.max`
> Max response time for failed responses of sampler name
>
> .ko.avg
> Average response time for failed responses of sampler name.
>
> `<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ko.pct<percentileValue>`
> Percentile computed for failed responses of sampler name. There will be one metric >for each calculated value.
>
> `<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.a.count`
> Number of responses for sampler name (sum of ok.count and ko.count)
>
> `<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.sb.bytes`
> Sent Bytes
>
> `<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.rb.bytes`
> Received Bytes
>
> `<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.a.min`
> Min response time for responses of sampler name (min of ok.count and ko.count)
>
> `<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.a.max`
> Max response time for responses of sampler name (max of ok.count and ko.count)
>
> `<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.a.avg`
> Average response time for responses of sampler name (avg of ok.count and ko.count)
>
> `<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.a.pct<percentileValue>`
> Percentile computed for responses of sampler name. There will be one metric for each >calculated value. (calculated on the totals for OK and failed samples)

If you need more information on configuring JMeter/InfluxDB/Grafana - check out [How to Use Grafana to Monitor JMeter Non-GUI Results - Part 2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results-part-2) article.

Comment: thanks! but i don't understand pct mean.. what is the pct?

Comment: It's kind of acronym for the [**percentile**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile). According to [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html): `90% Line (90th Percentile) is the value below which 90% of the samples fall. The remaining samples too at least as long as the value`. If you need more comprehensive explanation on percentiles - check out [Understanding Your Reports: Part 3 - Key Statistics Performance Testers Need to Understand](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/understanding-your-reports-part-3-key-statistics-performance-testers-need-understand)